# Connect MS SQL Server to Pentaho User Console using jtds driver from sourceforge.net

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, jtds

I want to connect my SQL Server to Pentaho. I use MS SQL SERVER 2000. For driver, I use jtds-1.3.1.jar that I download from sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files. However, I don't know how to do connection using this driver. Can anyone teach @ tell me where I can find tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you use JNDI, you can create the following code :

```
portal_db/type=javax.sql.DataSource
portal_db/driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
portal_db/url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS:1433;DatabaseName=DB_NAME;
portal_db/user=dbuser
portal_db/password=yourpassword
```

Or you can study with this url :

http://www.dbvis.com/doc/microsoft-sql-server-database-drivers/

Comment: in file jdbc.properties in folder data-integration\simple-jndi